# Brahman calf aggression?

Tags: safety, aggression, cows

My sister has a 7 month old brahman calf that charges at me. My niece is the one that takes care of him but with school it has been difficult for her to do so. As soon as i enter the pen he runs at me. He is a melon head so he has no horns but he is pretty strong. I’ve never mistreated him so i don’t understand why he does this. I’m starting to just leave his food near the door now. How can I correct this behavior?Thank you.

Comment: "Leave his food near the door". Perhaps he is angry at his confinement: not being able to roam freely.

Answer (score 1):

We cannot know why the calf started charging at you, but usually they percieve you as an intruder or competitor. I think the easiest way to change this behavior is by connecting your presence with something positive like food.

Every time you go to the pen, start talking or singing to him before you open the door. Cows can recognize and distinguish humans by their voice, so this tells him who is approaching. In some cultures it was custom that every farmer had their individual song they sang to call their own cows to them, see [Wikipedia for Kulning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kulning). It also warns him of your presence and avoids scaring him.

Then, stay at a place that is safe for you and where he either cannot charge at you or where you can easily dodge. Let him approach you and immediately hold some food in front of his nose. That can be his usual food but it's better to offer him some fresh herbs, or even a tasty fruit (or at least a piece of fruit) that smells good. The smell of the food is supposed to distract him from attacking you.

Once you have given him a little welcome treat, put his usual food in the pen and leave again.

It will take a few days of consistant "bribery" for him to remember that you always bring treats and hopefully to stop attacking you.

Another reason for his behavior can be your body language. Try to never look and walk directly in his direction, because that can be perceived as a confrontation. Instead, look slightly beside him and walk as if you want to pass him by.